# SSH access to WAN Raspberry Pi fails

Tags: networking, ssh

Ubuntu 16.04: A SSH connection from the WAN is made to a rPi: **Why is WAN SSH access successful, whereas LAN access attempts fails?**

Setup \ Network Configuration:

- A Raspberry Pi is guest connected Merlin Asus router: rPi = no LAN access.
- Port 130 traffic is forwarded to the rPi's standard SSH port 22

**Network access is configured so that rPI access is only through the WAN side of the router**: access is successful from devices that are outside the firewall.  Traffic between the rPi and LAN devices is blocked intentionally

```
ssh pi@73.224.XXX.YYY -p 130
```

Attempts to run the command from the LAN (firewalled) side of the router fail.  Does the ssh command require adjustment or is there a router setting change needed (maybe both)?

The goal is to be able to SSH from not only the outside WAN but the inside LAN.

Actionable guidance is appreciated

Comment: Does the ssh server run on port 130 or does the router forward external port 130 to the pi's port 22 ?

Comment: @pLumo: The latter:  The router forwards WAN port-130 traffic to the rPi's port-22

Comment: yes, attempting to use your external IP address from inside your LAN rarely works. It depends on the router, and most don't allow what you are trying.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd try is to connect to port 22 when on WAN, the router might not be redirecting port 130 on WAN.

I'd also try to do `telnet the-pi's-local-ip 130` then `telnet the-pi's-local-ip 22` to see if you get anything. That might help debug the issue.

Comment: Good idea:  SSH access to the rPI is successful from devices that are outside the firewall (WAN).   I have remote access to WAN Linux boxes to test from outside the LAN.  A successful WAN SSH connect to the pi confirms the router is forwarding traffic as expected